# How to add Product using module in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I'm using prestashop 1.5.1. In that I'm creating one module in which customer can post their product to store. I unable to find how to add product with help of module. can any one know solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

This may be rather a complex and non secure way, because you may miss some data validation and your shop may get non standard products. Anyway, below is the summarised detail how to do that.

First instantiate the Product Object Model object as below:

```
$productObj = new Product();
```

Now you have to set all the required properties for the product. It is a long list of properties which i cant mention here, but you can check them in the Classes/Product.php class. Also in that class you will be able to see the required data and other validations info. So follow those validation info to validate that data in your module.

To set product data, use code like below :

```
$productObj = new Product();
$productObj->id_default_category = 3; // lets consider default category is 3, it can be any
$productObj->id_quantity = 100; 
$productObj->price = 49.50;
....
....
....
```

This is for non language data fields / properties. As PS support multiple languages and default language is english which has ID 1. So lets consider you have two languages english with ID 1 and French with ID 2, you have to set the data as below:

```
$productObj->name = array(1 => 'Name in English', 2 => 'Name in French');
$productObj->description = array(1 => 'in English', 2 => 'in French');
...
...
```

After all these , just call the add method of the object model as below :

```
$productObj->add();
```

And thats it. If all goes fine, your product will be saved.

Also read the following post:

[add category programmatically prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720880/add-category-programmatically-prestashop)